# How to add matchers from jest-extended

Tags: jestjs, vite, vitest

I'm porting Jest tests to Vitest.

These tests use matchers from `jest-extended` like `expect(val).toBeString()`.
I tried to put `import "jest-extended"` in the test file, but the result is the error: `Error: Invalid Chai property: toBeString`.

I tried also to put in `vite.config.ts`:

```
    test: {
        environment: "happy-dom",
        globals: true,
        reporters: ["default", "html"],
        setupFiles: [
            "node_modules/jest-extended/dist/index.js",
        ]
    }
```

without change.
Even tried to use the `vitest-extended` package but also no change.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/getting-started/setup#use-with-vitest) says, you need to create setup file.

```js
// vitest.setup.js
import { expect } from 'vitest';
import * as matchers from 'jest-extended';

expect.extend(matchers);
```

Then you need to specify the path to it in the vitest configuration file

```js
// vitest.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    setupFiles: ['./vitest.setup.js'],
  },
});
```

More information about extending matchers can be found in the [vitest documentation](https://vitest.dev/guide/extending-matchers).